# When fitting a model with a test set in Sagemaker, is there a way to receive the predictions of the test set?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm training a model using Sagemaker, specifically the DeepAR image, and giving both train and test sets as inputs for the `fit` function. 
Example code:

```
image_name = sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator.get_image_uri(region, "forecasting-deepar", "latest")
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    image_name=image_name,
    role=role,
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
    base_job_name=job_name,
    output_path=s3_output_path
)

data_channels = {
    "train": s3_train_path,
    "test": s3_test_path
}

estimator.fit(inputs=data_channels, wait=True, job_name=model_name)
```

I see some test result metrics at the end of the prints of the training, but I would like to get the actual predictions to analyse. Example of test result metrics:

```
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, RMSE): 819.800852342
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, mean_wQuantileLoss): 0.33004057
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.1]): 0.12110487
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.2]): 0.20682412
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.3]): 0.2760827
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.4]): 0.3326178
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.5]): 0.37820518
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.6]): 0.41009128
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.7]): 0.42785496
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.8]): 0.42626995
[12/25/2019 13:02:26 INFO 139821722212160] #test_score (algo-1, wQuantileLoss[0.9]): 0.3913141
```

The best that I have found is not uploading a test set at all, and separately running a `batch_transform` job to get the test predictions back.
[Docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase) are vague saying regarding estimator `output_path`:

> S3 location for saving the training result (model artifacts and output files)

Not sure what that includes.
Is there a way to get the predictions of the test set?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker training job is an automation wrapper that allows your code to run in a local mode. When your code needs a file, it can get it from the local disk. When the model is saving a file, it does that to the local disk. SageMaker is responsible to copy the data that is needed as input from S3 to the local disk, and then copy that data that you write as output back to S3. The channels that you provide are giving SageMaker that locations in S3 to copy from and to. The names of the channels are the names of the folders in the local disk.

If your code is writing out the predictions, they will be copied to S3, and you will be able to process them. If you are using the AWS built-in algorithm that is using their Docker image to run the DeepAR algorithm, it will **not** write out the predictions.

You have two options:

- Write your own code to wrap the DeepAR algorithm and in your code write the predictions after the last iteration to the output folder.
- More simply, run the batch prediction API with the test data.

In both cases, it is better if you split the data into **three** groups as the score on the test data that was used as validation data, is not going to be a good estimator for the performance of your model on new unseen data. If you do that, running the batch predictions on the test data makes even more sense.

Comment: Is there a reason DeepAR does not write out predictions?

I agree with the options, currently using the 2 one. Regarding splitting the data, not sure I understand why to use 3 groups. I see in the logs that the use of the test data occurs only after the model is trained if I'm not mistaken, and if so 2 groups (one for train, second for evaluation) is enough.

Comment: The logs I'm basing on -

Without test:

```[01/02/2020 14:52:47 INFO 140454633060160] No test data passed, skipping evaluation.
```

With test:

```[01/02/2020 17:31:26 INFO 140715580856128] Evaluating model accuracy on testset using 100 samples```

Is there any reference in the docs that the test set is used as validation?